# UWP CreateFile2 ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER on opening a device

Tags: uwp, device

We have C++ dll that is P/Invoked in a UWP app. The dll opens a USB device using the CreateFile function.

```
hDevice = CreateFile("\\\\.\\EZUSB_FX2", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0, NULL);
```

All work fine, except that our app has to be side loaded.

Moving forward we have replaced most of the non-compliant functions in the C++ dll with compliant ones.

However while opening the device with CreateFile2, it fails with the error code ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER

```
hDevice = CreateFile2(L"\\\\.\\EZUSB_FX2", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL);
```

What is the recommended way to open a device through Win32 calls in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfile2),

> When called from a Windows Store app, CreateFile2 is simplified. You can open only files or directories inside the ApplicationData.LocalFolder or Package.InstalledLocation directories. You can't open named pipes or mailslots or create encrypted files (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED).

That's the reason why you get the error.
If you want to create file in your usb device the better way is that use UWP [`RemovableDevices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_RemovableDevices) api. For more detail please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card). If you insist on using win32 api, maybe you need to think about desktopbridge technology.

Comment: That is very disappointing. I wonder under what logic DeviceIoControl is permitted in UWP but not a function like CreateFile in the first place?
We already have a side loaded app and it is a retrograde step to think of using Desktop Bridge.
Using UWP API is beyond our competence.
We would rather continue to use CreateFile and Side Load our app. I hope MS will be able to give a solution in the near future.